# Working With CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to store only 20 Notifications which include 
"Title,Detail and Received Time" fields inside Notifications Table.But,I only found solution for working `CoreData` with CRUD some example.But,I am still seeking for working with limitation when user fetch new results from api inside device database.That is where I am stuck.I don't know how to do it using `CoreData` because I was beginner at that.

Requirement :

1.Application can only store 20 Records maximum.So,when it reach max length,it will do First-In-Last-Out to Notifications table base on Notifications Received Time.**(First Problem)**

2.Every time the user do pull to refresh,my app fetch new notification from Web-Backend and replace or overwrite on user device database when it successfully download new notifications like "Push Notification Service App" on App Store.**(Second Problem)**

I really need a hand to pick up with core data flow which I am stucking at things I am not familiar with.

Any help or guide please?(Posting Sample with .json is appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a service, like RestKit or similar, to support your web service interaction. Each record should have a unique identifier supplied by the server so you can find an existing copy and update it instead of needing to delete everything and recreated it.

To trim your data use a fetch request with a `fetchOffset` and a `sortDescriptors` by date. This allows you to skip the newest 20 items and gives you a list of everything that needs to be deleted. If you're using RestKit you can supply this fetch request in a fetch request block and the deletion will be done for you.

Comment: Sorry,I only know swift syntax,I am just developer who just change from java to swift ios platform.So,using RestKit is impossible to me.Any further help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: There are tutorials / examples on the web, like http://blog.zymr.com/how-to-use-restkit-in-swift-for-ios-development

Answer (score 2):

use NSUserDefaults for that if your data size is small